# How to intall ungoogled-chromium on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, chromium

I tried to install ungoogled-chromium from [download page](https://ungoogled-software.github.io/ungoogled-chromium-binaries/) but I couldn't manage to install any package, and since I am not sure how it works, so I would like to have an instruction of how to install this.

Every time I use `dpkg -i` to install downloaded packages it just tells me dependencies are missing.

For example, this package is considered the "official" package:

```
sudo dpkg -i ungoogled-chromium_69.0.3497.100-1.bionic_amd64.deb

Selecting previously unselected package ungoogled-chromium.
(Reading database ... 289494 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ungoogled-chromium_69.0.3497.100-1.bionic_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ungoogled-chromium (69.0.3497.100-1~bionic) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ungoogled-chromium:
 ungoogled-chromium depends on libminizip1 (>= 1.1); however:
  Package libminizip1 is not installed.
 ungoogled-chromium depends on libre2-4 (>= 20160901); however:
  Package libre2-4 is not installed.
 ungoogled-chromium depends on ungoogled-chromium-common (= 69.0.3497.100-1~bionic); however:
  Package ungoogled-chromium-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ungoogled-chromium (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ungoogled-chromium
```

Other packages also have similar problems, those I downloaded are:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kuai kuai  41965828 jun 18 10:58  ungoogled-chromium_69.0.3497.100-1.bionic_amd64.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kuai kuai     20722 jun 18 10:59  ungoogled-chromium-browser_69.0.3497.100-1.bionic_amd64.buildinfo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kuai kuai   2215920 jun 18 11:00  ungoogled-chromium-driver_69.0.3497.100-1.bionic_amd64.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kuai kuai   2768780 jun 11 06:30  ungoogled-chromium-l10n_69.0.3497.100-1.bionic_all.deb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kuai kuai  27513584 jun 18 11:00  ungoogled-chromium-shell_69.0.3497.100-1.bionic_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Add the full output of `dpkg -i` please.

Comment: Please see the original post added with the log. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From inside the folder containing the chromium-ungoogled .debs type:

sudo apt-get install libminizip1 libre2-4 ungoogled-chromium*.deb

Note: make sure all of the chromium-ungoogled .deb files are there, including the common one.

Comment: It doesn' work... these libraries can not be found in apt

Comment: Hey, update, I got it by doing `sudo dpkg -i ./*` and then `sudo apt -fix--broken install`. Thanks anyway.