# How to install ungoogled-chromium on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: browser

I have read that the `ungoogled-chromium` web browser is not only free from Google services and tracking, but unlike other Chromium forks it is essentially a direct replacement for Chromium, featuring tweaks to improve privacy, control and transparency.
Is there any procedure to install and keep it updated in Ubuntu 20.04?
Thank you very much in advance.

The posts about it do not clarify my doubts.

Comment: what is confusing about the 4 lines of code you need to copy/paste? See https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium-debian

Comment: @Rinzwind:Thank you very much for your attention. I was referring specifically to what I found on the site:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151936/how-to-intall-ungoogled-chromium-on-ubuntu-18-04.

Answer (score 7):

Ungoogled-chromium can conflict with Chromium, if it is installed, so you should first uninstall it.

To do this, open a terminal and run in it:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge chromium
```

The project is in the openSUSE repositories, to install it from there, you would have to perform a series of instructions:

In principle add the repository to the sources.list file running in terminal:

```
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/ungoogled_chromium/Ubuntu_Focal/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:ungoogled_chromium.list
```

Then we would have to add the public key by executing in the terminal:

```
sudo wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:ungoogled_chromium/Ubuntu_Focal/Release.key -O "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:ungoogled_chromium.asc"
```

Now it only remains to update the system and install it, running in terminal:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install ungoogled-chromium
```

Using this method, you make sure you keep it updated with each new version, that the project team keeps updating.

On this site, you can obtain information about the program, as well as obtain the binaries to install it manually:

https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium#feature-overview

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.

Comment: Thank you for not being elitist or condescending, the information was useful.

Comment: M. Knepper: Thanks to you for what you said, I am glad to have been useful. Just for that I participate. I do not share mistreatment or intemperance.

Comment: Deprecated; no longer available.

Comment: Resource is no longer available!

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the ungoogled-chromium github page (here: https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium), you will see a link to distribution specific instructions (here: https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium-debian), where it shows how to add the repository and install with apt. These are the instructions for Ubuntu Focal (20.04):

```
# echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/ungoogled_chromium/Ubuntu_Focal/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home-ungoogled_chromium.list > /dev/null
# curl -s 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/ungoogled_chromium/Ubuntu_Focal/Release.key' | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home-ungoogled_chromium.gpg > /dev/null
# sudo apt update
# sudo apt install -y ungoogled-chromium
```